# Android: Process Dialog cycle through different strings

Tags: android, process

I was wondering if it would be possible when I have a process dialog thread pop-up to have text able to cycles through a series of different strings. Kind of like the old SimCity games when you created a new city it would say:
"Building
TeraForming
Populating
etc."

haha Not the best example but that is the first thing that comes to mind. I use this for a basic dialog:

```
private class LoadingThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
                Thread.sleep(8000);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MyClass.this)
        .setMessage(result).setCancelable(false).setTitle("Title")
        .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        ).show();
      }
    }
```

Its called with:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.progressDialog = 
        ProgressDialog.show(
                this,                             
                "String 1",
                "String 2"
        );
    new LoadingThread().execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against using a timer as loading time is never constant. Instead , depending on what you are loading , use the progress percentage to change the title or text .